# Best way to capture barcodes using Motorola MC2180 or similar mobile scanner

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, mobile

1d/2D Barcodes needs captured using cordless barcode scanner and transferred to Windows PC.
I looked into Motorola MC2180 mobile computer specifications.
It seems to have Windows CE 6 with RhoElements Webkit based browser and Datawedge application which  transfers scanned barcodes to keyboard buffers.

Scanning application prototype using ASP.NET MVC4 is below.

This approach has the following issues:

1. After scanning barcode, user must press manually tab to move to next field.
   Is there some barcode APIS which can used ? I havent found any documentations for this 
   for MC2180 .
2. View below looks ugly: it allows to scan fixed number codes, but user may wat to enter 1 .. 200 codes to single order. How to change it so that number of codes in not fixed ?
   Should jQuery Mobile used to improve this or other way ?
3. Controller perfoms manual parsing of http POST buffer. Can this improved using ASP.NET MVC4 features ?

Which is best way to scan barcodes in cordless way and transfer them to PC using free 
or shipped with scanner shoftware ?
Which device shuld be used ?
If there is better cheap device than MC2180 it can used.

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<form method='post' action='SaveOrder'>

Number <input name='orderno' type='text'/>
Date <input name='orderdate' type='date'/>

<input type="hidden" name="_rowdelimiter" />
Product1 <input name='orderno' type='text'/>
Quantity1 <input name='quantity' type='text'/>

<input type="hidden" name="_rowdelimiter" />
Product2 <input name='orderno' type='text'/>
Quantity2 <input name='quantity' type='text'/>

<input type="hidden" name="_rowdelimiter" />
Product3 <input name='orderno' type='text'/>
Quantity3 <input name='quantity' type='text'/>
...
<input type='submit' value='Save order'/>    
</form>
</body></html>
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveOrder() {
  var form = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
  var orderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>();
  var order = new Order();
  OrderDetails row = null;
  bool inheader = true;
  foreach (var key in form.AllKeys)
    {
    if (key == "_rowdelimiter")
      {
        if (row != null)
          orderDetails.Add(row);
          row = new OrderDetails();
          inheader = false;
          continue;
          }
        if (inheader)
         {
          SetValue( order, key, HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(form[key]) );
          continue;
          }
       SetValue( row, key, HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(form[key]) );
   }
  orderDetails.Add(row);
  EntityManager.SaveOrder( order, orderDetails );
  return ContentResult() {Content="Order saved" } ;
}

static void SetValue( object entity, string propertyName, string propertyValue ) {
  PropertyInfo p = entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
  p.SetValue(this, propertyValue, null);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off using jQuery in the page to handle the scanned barcode. It could take each code & add it to an array. This array could then be listed on screen. When the operator has scanned some number of codes, they could click a button to submit the codes to the server. Your app would appear to be much more responsive that way, rather than submitting after each scan.

Comment: Code in question collects scanned codes to form. All codes are submitted together, codes are submitted only if submit button is pressed. If I understand properly, you recommend to have single row. After scanning new row shoudl be added automatically to allow next code scanning or data from filled row should be copied to other row. Where to find such code sample or how to implement this: fill row, press enter and after that new rows appears in table.